# android bitmap and opencv mat - Same code different outcome

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-bitmap, mat

The code I wrote act like this:

1. take a Bitmap
2. convert it to Mat
3. process the pixels
4. convert the Mat to Bitmap

At this point I have two branches. The first one displays the bitmap into an ImageView, the second one saves the bitmap on disk and **then** displays the bitmap into an ImageView.
Despite using the same code, I'm facing different behaviours. I would like the bitmap I'm saving to preserve colors as in the first case.
This is the code I'm using:

```
srcBitmap = ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath,1024,1024,null);

src = new Mat(srcBitmap.getHeight(),srcBitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);
dst = new Mat(srcBitmap.getHeight(),srcBitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8UC4);

Utils.bitmapToMat(srcBitmap,src);
Utils.bitmapToMat(srcBitmap,dst);

double[] rgb;
for(i=0; i<src.height(); i++){
    for(j=0; j<src.width(); j++){
        rgb = src.get(i,j);

        r = rgb[0];
        g = rgb[1];
        b = rgb[2];
        a = rgb[3];
        .
        .
        .
        dst.put(i,j, r, g, b,a);
        }
}

Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcBitmap.getWidth(),srcBitmap.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(dst,dstBitmap);
```

**First case: just display the bitmap**

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap_preview);                
imageView.setImageBitmap(dstBitmap);
```

**Second case: save the bitmap and display**

```
File newFile = fileHandler.getOutputMediaFile(FileHandler.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
FileOutputStream out = null;
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
    destBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bitmap_preview);                
imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(fileHandler.getUriFromFile(newFile).getPath(),1024,1024,null));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort out the problem by changing the inizialization of the Mat this way:

```
    src = new Mat(bufferBitmap.getHeight(),bufferBitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
    dst = new Mat(bufferBitmap.getHeight(),bufferBitmap.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
```

**Edit**

After saving the file make sure to call

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[]{file.toString()}, null, null);
```

So that the OS can properly index the new file, more details in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661197/why-does-saving-a-bitmap-take-so-long)